# 2 threads increasing a static integer

Tags: c#

if i am increasing a static by 2 different Tasks or Threads do i need to lock it?

i have this class which will be used by multiple threads at the same time, it returns a proxy to be used inside a thread but i dont want to use the same proxy at the same time with each thread, so i thought incrementing a static integer is the best way, any suggestions?

```
class ProxyManager
{
    //static variabl gets increased every Time GetProxy() gets called
    private static int Selectionindex;
    //list of proxies
    public static readonly string[] proxies = {};
    //returns a web proxy
    public static WebProxy GetProxy()
    {
      Selectionindex = Selectionindex < proxies.Count()?Selectionindex++:0;
      return new WebProxy(proxies[Selectionindex]) { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx") };
    }
}
```

based on the selected answer

```
if(Interlocked.Read(ref Selectionindex) < proxies.Count())
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref Selectionindex);
}
else
{
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref Selectionindex, 0);
}

Selectionindex = Interlocked.Read(ref Selectionindex);
```

Comment: "if i am increasing a static by 2 different Tasks or Threads do i need to lock it?"  Only if you want the right answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you increment a static variable across threads you will end up with inconsistent results. Instead use [Interlocked.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.increment.aspx):

```
private void IncrementSelectionIndex() {
    Interlocked.Increment(ref Selectionindex);
}
```

64-bit reads are atomic, but to fully support 32-bit systems you should use [Interlocked.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.read.aspx)

```
private void RetrieveSelectionIndex() {
    Interlocked.Read(ref Selectionindex);
}
```

Comment: `Interlocked.Add` should be also used to set the variable back to 0: `Interlock.Add(SelectionIndex, -SelectionIndex);`

Comment: Yes, or `Interlocked.Exchange(ref Selectionindex, 0)`... if you use `-SelectionIndex` you'd have to use `Interlocked.Read` to be safe on 32-bit systems and even then... could still create a problem unless you placed the `Interlocked.Add` inside a locked block locking on an arbitrary `object`.

Comment: @cfeduke please check the updated code in my question, is it alright?

Comment: Appears to be. I'd encapsulate the usage of `Selectionindex` into its own class (singleton or static, named something like `AtomicCount`) with methods like `Get` (`Interlocked.Read`), `Reset` (`Interlocked.Exchange`) and a `bool IsLessThan(Int32)` to replace the `if` conditional's test. I would do this for maintainability and readability.